# Password Issue when trying to update User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement a forgot/recover password emailer for my application, but am having issues with saving the token. I'm using has_secure_password and password_digest for security.

This is my controller

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    flash[:notice] = 'E-mail sent with password reset instructions.'
    redirect_to new_session_path
  end
```

This is within the User model

```
def send_password_reset
        generate_token(:password_reset_token)
        self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
        save!
        UserMailer.forgot_password(self).deliver# 
      end
     
      def generate_token(column)
        begin
          self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
      end
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters):
  app/models/user.rb:11:in `send_password_reset'
  app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

I'm just confused about how to validate the user without their password so that I'm able to update their internal fields(recoverytoken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it when using `has_secure_password`. The key here is the `unless` part.

```rb
validates :password, presence: true, on: :update, length: { minimum: 5 }, 
  unless: proc { |x| x.password.blank? }
```